# Fourier transform of Gaussian noise

Tags: fourier-analysis

So I was doing a Fourier transform on a Gaussian distribution, the histogram of which is as follows. And by the way I sampled a million data, as shown in the image.
[image]
What is such distribution?
I find Weibull Distribution and Beta Distribution similar to the histogram, but I'm not sure.

Comment: The Fourier Transform of a Gaussian should be another Gaussian. Are you sure your code is correct? The histogram you show there is skewed, which I would not expect in a Gaussian.

Comment: You're taking the absolute value in there, right? Is that what you want to do? It's no longer a Gaussian at that point.

Comment: Indeed, I intentionally took the absolute value, as I don’t suppose it is poossible to draw a histogram of complex data

Comment: What I was wondering was that what this distribution is.

Comment: And thank you so much for helping

Answer (score 0):

The magnitude of the signal follows a Rice distribution:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice_distribution

Comment: Welcome to Math SE! Can you elaborate a bit more on your answer?